# How to fix error The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly. in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a xamarin forms project that was working so fine on visual studio 2017, but when I have updated to visual studio 2019 it throws an error

**Error The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'SoftGrowth.PharmaciesApp.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'SoftGrowth.PharmaciesApp.Android.dll'**

I tried to delete bin & obj folder than clean and rebuild but nothing happened.
I tried to change the compile and target version but no result.

**The compiling version: Android 8.1 (Oreo)
The minimum android version: Android 8.0 API Level 26 - Oreo
Target android version: Android 8.1 API Level 27 - Oreo
Linking: None**

I need to fix this error and make the application compile on minimum android version 8.0 API 26

**Update**

I have created a new project and moved the files from my project to the new project, everything was OK till **Xam.Plugin.Media** package installed to the new project.

Comment: You can  try to delete the Xamarin.Forms package and re-add it via NuGet.

Comment: Also, why are you keeping the minimum version so high?

Comment: This is usually indicative of another build issue. The actual error is causing the failure which in turn causes the link assemblies to fail. There isn't another error buried in the output window when you build?

Comment: @JessieZhang no didn't work :(

Comment: @G.hakim I just try to find any solution for this issue. I tried a lower versions and didn't work. BTW when I tried to publish apk with minimum 25 the google play didn't accept that and showed that the target version must be at least 26

Comment: @ottermatic Yes some errors in **Resource.designer.cs** file. I have mentioned these error in other topic and got reply to ignore it. I don't think these errors are related to that error in this topic, but I think it related to **Xam.Plugin.Media**, because I tried to remove each installed package in the project, and that package removed the error but of course showed other code errors

Comment: @AmirImam Did you have the Xam.Plugin.Media nuget package installed in both the Forms and Android project? Were the errors in Resource.designer.cs complaining about elements not existing? Or were they your normal Android compilation warnings?

Comment: @ottermatic Yes the package installed in both projects. The errors are shown with any new android project with vs 2019, and I can remove them with just clean and build. That is why I think they are not related to the that error.

Comment: @ottermatic Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test this question ？